# How to add a UIview above the current view controllers view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an Ipad application in which i am trying to do some barcode reading processes.when  i am pressing a button in the home page i am presenting the barcode reading viewcontrollers view like this`

```
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;

    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    reader.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    //reader.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

    reader.cameraOverlayView=cameraOverlay;

    if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:                         UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront ])
    {
           reader.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    }
    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

    reader.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance

    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];
     reader.showsZBarControls = NO; 
    // present and release the controller
   [self presentModalViewController:reader animated:YES];
    //[appdel.navigationController pushViewController:reader animated:YES];

    //[reader.view addSubview:collect];
    [reader.view addSubview:back];
      [back addTarget:self action:@selector(backpressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [reader.view addSubview:scan];
    [scan addTarget:self action:@selector(getpressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [reader release];
```

and when i am pressing the scan button added to the reader view i need to add another view.for that i am doing `-(IBAction)getpressed:(id)sender{[self.view addSubview:newview]  }`.but it is not added to the view.can anybody help me to achieve this?
`

Comment: Tried with `[self.view addSubView:newView.view];`?

Comment: Did you check that the getpressed method is called ? and who is newview ???

Comment: yes[self.view addSubView:newView.view] it is tried no luck

Comment: Think you need to use `cameraOverlayView` again.

Answer (score 1):

you need to overlay to your zbar view and add that button overlay view:

```
//set the frame according to your requirement 
aOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,320.0,480.0)]; 
aOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIButton *aBtnscan  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[aBtnscan setFrame:CGRectMake(115, 435, 80, 45)];

[aBtnscan addTarget:self action:@selector(getpressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[aOverlay addSubview:aBtnscan];
reader.cameraOverlayView = aOverlay; 
// You code
```